# Laravel 5.1 - Querying multiple relationships

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've got a problem which I don't know how to solve.
I've got companies which have a profile(profile belongs to company) and have locations(company has many locations).

I'm trying to get all companies which have a name like `$request->input('search_term')` and have a least one location with a zip or city matching `$request->input('search_addition')` and a profile with a type of 0.

My code is:

```
$companies = Company::with(['profile' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('type', 0);

                }])
                ->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('zip', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_addition').'%')
                          ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_addition').'%');
                })
                ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_term').'%');
```

At the end I add `$companies = $companies->paginate(25);`

The result I get is not what I want. I get all companies which have a name like `$request->input('search_term')`. It ignores the type of the profile and the locations. The locations array is empty for those companies which don't match the specified search_addition but it still returns the company.

Answer (score 0):

`with()` is used for relationship eager loading either with or without constraint, not used as a constraint to filter the parent model which you need to use `where` function family instead.

This is what I think the code should be (not tested).

```
$companies = Company::with('profile')
    ->with(['locations' => function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('zip', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_addition').'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_addition').'%');
    }])
    ->whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 0);
    })
    ->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('zip', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_addition').'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_addition').'%');
    })
    ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search_term').'%');
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. Back to the drawing board I guess. Your hint about "with" was good though. Maybe I can solve the problem this way.